# Python numpy 'same' convolution different from Matlab's?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to replicate Matlab's convolution aka conv function.

Matlab's conv works like this:

```
w = conv(u,v,shape) returns a subsection of the convolution, as specified by shape. For example, conv(u,v,'same') returns only the central part of the convolution, the same size as u.
```

I tried numpy convolve but documentation says it work differently, in fact:

numpy.convolve(a, v, mode) where:

- a(N,) array_like
- v(M,) array_like
- mode{‘full’, ‘valid’, ‘same’}

but the problem is that 'same' does NOT work as Matlab, in fact it says:

```
Mode ‘same’ returns output of length max(M, N).
```

But I don't want the output to be of length `max(M,N)`.

I want it to be `same size as u` as Matlab's.

Any idea how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You could just calculate the full convolution and trim it to the input size afterwards, provided you have enough RAM. Just remove the first and last 25% of all rows/columns, and retain an `m,n` sized centre piece. This should be the same as what MATLAB outputs when applying the `'same'` switch

Comment: is there a quick way to cut the first and last 25% of all rows and columns? This way I could at least assess if the values would be ok by doing so

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Python syntax anymore, but I'd say you could obtain the `data.shape()`, then divide that by 4, this gives you 25% of the rows/columns, and `data.shape()` times `3/4` gives you 75%.

Comment: can I ask you how did you come up with the 25%? I'm trying to figure out what could be the ratio by examining the values I have but I can't. For example in one case Matlab's same conv produces 971 values, while Python full conv produces 1571 (600 values more). In another case Matlab's same conv produces 451, while Python full conv produces 1051 (600 values more). In another case Matlab's same conv produces 59 values, while Python full conv produces 119 (60 values more). It shouldn't be 25%, at least according to these experiments